# Apply a shader to the right face of a mesh

Tags: unity, blender, unity-shader-graph

Given that I don't have the basic concepts to work with 3d, I would still like to experiment and learn.

What have I done:

1. I imported an SVG of the world map into Blender
2. I extruded the SVG
3. I converted everything to mesh
4. I exported the FBX and imported into Unity.
   Great, it works!

I then created a flag shader (following a tutorial), India in this case, and then applied the material to the India mesh.

[image]

The result is that it applies to the wrong faces! Obviously I wanted it to apply to the surface, not the extruded side.

[image]

**What are the notions I'm missing, how do I correct this dynamic?**

*Thank you.*

Comment: You need to [set up a UV unwrap in Blender](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=uv+mapping+in+blender) before you import the mesh into Unity.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks Gregory! I just tried it and now the shader is applied to the surface (it's not scaled as I would like, but that's the fault of the shader itself I think). Thank you so much!

Comment: Be sure to post an answer below explaining the steps you took, so that this thread can help future users struggling with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, as suggested by DMGregory, I did the following steps (on Blender):

1. Enter the "UV Editing" workspace
2. I selected all the meshes that I needed to export. So:
3. Press `TAB` to enter Edit Mode
4. Press `a` to select all meshes
5. Press `u` to open the `UV Mapping` menu
6. Select `Unwrap`

[image]

Export.

I hope it's accurate, I've been using Blender for a few days.